# Functions between ordered sets

Tags: functions, order-theory

Many studies try to define functions between ordered set and prove monotoniciy of such functions. What are the possible benefits of such functions without considering that they are always increasing or decreasing.

Comment: If they are strictly monotonic then they will be injective (one-to-one) and so there may be some sort of inverse function in some sense

Comment: They're useful for manipulating inequalities, since applying an increasing function $f$ to both sides of an inequality preserves the inequality. e.g., $x \leq y \implies \log(x) \leq \log(y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They preserve the order.  Therefore, it one sorted array is monotonically mapped to another, the latter is automatically sorted.

Comment: Thanks. That's a good answer. But I wonder if there are any other benefits.

Comment: That's basically the only purpose of monotonicity.

Comment: All other benefits are, fundamentally, based on preserving the order.  But these benefits include some key and advanced results; e.g., [Monotone Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem).